# Index error: List index out of range in list exercise

Tags: python, list

I am trying to learn Python and going through the codeacademy course. Unfortunately I've gotten to an error and don't know how to fix it. The hint doesn't help either. The goal is to make a new list out of the list-with-2-lists.

Could anyone explain what I've done wrong?

[image]

Thank you very much,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do

```
for i in numbers:
```

`i` will have the actual value of the `numbers` list in every iteration, **not the index**. So, you can straight away `append` it to `results`, like this

```
results.append(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is in

```
for i in numbers:
```

this line will not return you `index` of element, but it will return you element itself.

Check this

Values only

```
>>> [value for value in iter(range(10, 20))]
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
```

Values with index

```
>>> [(index, value) for index, value in enumerate(range(10, 20))]
[(0, 10), (1, 11), (2, 12), (3, 13), (4, 14), (5, 15), (6, 16), (7, 17), (8, 18), (9, 19)]
```